# Navigation Controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm new to iOS app development and just started playing around with Xcode.
I was wondering if the Navigation Controller is necessary? If what I'm creating doesn't require a back button or forward button, do I still need it? Or should I just hide it?

Thanks!

Comment: With due respect, you should read this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) to know about `UINavigationController` and the cases where it should be used. This question is too broad to answer here.

Comment: You should use Single View Application if you don't need Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1):

> try this code in viewDidLoad

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if the Navigation Controller is necessary? If what I'm
>   creating doesn't require a back button or forward button, do I still
>   need it?

Definitely no. There is a dedicated "Single View Application" template in Xcode, that creates a navigation-less, tab-less app precisely for these kind of case.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't require a back button or forward button then no need to navigation controller. You can hide navigation controller using..

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate from one VC to another VC than only navigation is required else you can take simple VC no need to take navigation controller and mark your VC as initial VC